# ELI5 How does a Merkle-Patricia-trie tree work?

Tags: blockchain, merkle-patricia-tries

I understand that *Merkle tree* are Hashes of Hashes, they have the advantage that you can verify only a subtree. But what about *Patricia*? What does a *trie* mean? And how is it used in Ethereum?

Comment: https://medium.com/@chiqing/merkle-patricia-trie-explained-ae3ac6a7e123

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**Trie (also called digital tree, prefix trie or radix trie)**

An ordered tree data structure that is used to store a dynamic set or associative array where the keys are usually strings. A node's position in the tree defines the key with which it is associated.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

[image]

*A trie for keys "A","to", "tea", "ted", "ten", "i", "in", and "inn".*

**Patricia** - *Practical Algorithm To Retrieve Information Coded In Alphanumeric* ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree#History))([orginial paper by Donald R. Morrison](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321481)). A Patricia trie is a [binary radix trie](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/63060/44807) - binary choice at each node when traversing the trie; this is modified in Ethereum.

[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:An_example_of_how_to_find_a_string_in_a_Patricia_trie.png

In ethereum, hexadecimal is used - X characters from an 16 character "alphabet". Hence nodes in the trie have 16 child nodes (the 16 character hex "alphabet") and a maximum depth of X. Note a hex character is referred to as a "nibble".

**Merkle Patricia Trie**

As described [here](https://easythereentropy.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/understanding-the-ethereum-trie/), the term Merkle implies that

> the root node becomes a cryptographic fingerprint of the entire data
>   structure

**Ethereum Modified Merkle Patricia Trie**

The yellow paper describes a modified merkle patricia trie. This defines three different node types; extension, branch and leaf. These are descibed, using a simplified world state, in the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't a key under `world-state` contain 8 nibble (32 bytes)? In your example(latest image) it contains 7 nibbles, which is 28 bytes. @atomh33ls

Comment: @Alper thanks... I shortened it to make it more concise. I think 8 nibbles is just 4 bytes... and 7 is 3.5 bytes. I'd need 64 hex chars for 32 bytes...

Comment: What do the leaf node and extension nodes of the trie do?

Comment: Thanks! How does a stale tree synchronize to an up-to-date tree? (e.g., when a client gets online after one day). Does it just download the entire up-to-date tree, or some kind of "diff" is received for the synchronization?

Comment: @HelinWang No problem, I think this depends on the implementation so would be better posed as a new question...

Comment: Thank you @atomh33ls ! I just skimmed through the go eth trie source code, it seems there is another kind of node: hashNode, if my understanding is correct, it's a reference to any kind of node illustrated your graph in the database. Maybe your graph could be improved by pointing that out.

Answer (score 10):

'Trie' comes from the word retrieval, since it only uses the prefix of a word to find it in a dictionary. It is an ordered tree where the keys are usually strings ending with a terminal symbol, and each vertex represents a prefix. The root of a trie is usually an empty string, as we can see in the diagram taken from wikipedia.

[image: Diagram from wikipedia]

For more information about the difference between a trie and a radix (Patricia) tree.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708134/what-is-the-difference-between-trie-and-radix-trie-data-structures

More specifications of the Merkle Patricia tree that Ethereum uses can be found on the ethereum blog

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/