# How to get the list of all Ethereum addresses (with AND without balance)

Tags: blockchain, addresses, list

In order to make a full analysis of Ethereum's blockchain, I need a list with all the Ethereum addresses ever appeared. The size of this file does not matter.

On internet I have only found the list with all the addresses of positive balance, so it would be sufficient to get the full list of all the addresses which have appeared in Ethereum's history and that now are empty.

I would like to do it (preferably) without downloading the whole blockchain. How can I do it?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This should partly answer your question : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/how-to-list-all-ethereum-addresses-with-a-positive-balance , just make the modifications to retain only the accounts that fit your selection scheme. One way or another, you'll have to go through every block, as this is the only history (that I know of) allowing you to come up with the desired result.