# Can someone provide a detailed picture of an Ethereum Patricia Tree?

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries

I am looking for a diagram of a Patricia tree which shows the details of multiple blocks, with multiple transactions in each block. I want to see an actual example of how the chain of blocks will be represented, so I can understand how all of the components will be created i.e. header, extension, branch, leaf etc. It would be great if someone could provide that detailed picture.

I came across this [diagram](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/eli5-how-does-a-merkle-patricia-trie-tree-work) (i.e. the one showing extension branch & leaf). This diagram seems to be showing details of only one block with multiple transactions. I am looking for a diagram offering similar details but with multiple blocks, each involving multiple transactions.

Comment: You also might be interested to check out this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/6424/24693).

Answer (score 5):

I think the below picture might be the closest you will get. It can be found in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/757/52) answer to a previous question:

[Ethereum block architecture](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture/757#757)

Note that the purpose of this diagram is to show how the *state* tries for different blocks are related. The *transaction* tries are rather more straightforward. (i.e. They're just standalone, non-interacting data structures).

As an aside, to search for posts containing pictures on Stack Exchange, you can use something like `url:"*.png"` as the search term. (You can change the file extension for other picture types.)

[As a second aside, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZGxe.png) picture from the post you linked to is, to be honest, amazing, though again, for the state.]

[image: ![Ethereum Blockchain Architecture]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Richard. Overall its pretty confusing. If you refer to the diagram which is showing the world state (i.e. one you said amazing) it talks about the extension node, branch node, leaf node etc. Does that mean that each block is having its own such kind of tree structure. secondly the block at the top will be mapped to a previous block with more transactions which again internally will have its own tree (i.e. having extension node, branch node etc.). This is actually confusing me and that's why want to see a more detailed diagram.

Comment: In the world state diagram which one is the transaction tree or state tree?

Lets say if I have to create previous block diagram for this world state diagram then will it be in similar look with different world states listed. Can we discuss sometime in this regard in case you are available sometime.