# I don't understand this part of the Ethereum Documentation (storageRoot)

Tags: accounts, storage, merkle-patricia-tries, account-generation

This is from the account part of the Ethereum Docs, 4 fields of an account were described of which i am unable to understand this one.
(storageRoot)

[image]

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: almost everything after "root node of a Merkle Patricia trie....."

Comment: Here you'll find an explanation how a patricia trie works https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/eli5-how-does-a-merkle-patricia-trie-tree-work. Read carefully and if you have another doubt you can update the question to add the specific doubt.